# How to open Keyboard on Button click in android?

Tags: android, button, keyboard

How can I open Keyboard on Button click in android?

What I want to be like this:

[image]

Answer (score 34):

Please try this

```
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            imm.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED,0);
```

Comment: Thanks Sandy, the trick is InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED instead of InputMethodManager. SHOW_IMPLICIT.

Comment: this seems deprecated. is there any new way to do it as of 2022?

Answer (score 10):

```
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) activity.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);

imm.showSoftInput(view, flags)
```

an example may be:

```
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) RouteMapActivity.this
    .getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imm.showSoftInput(mapView, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
```

Comment: This is the correct answer. Other answers toggle the keyboard which is not desirable in many circumstances (i.e. we want to only SHOW the keyboard when user clicks the clear search field button, even if it is shown already)

Answer (score 3):

Write this code inside the Button click event to TOGGLE the keyboard:

```
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imm.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED,0);
```

Comment: @Paresh.....still not open keyboard on button click so please give me propre answer

Comment: @PareshMayani if i want to open the keyboard of specific language.Suppose of click of button i want to open a Hindi Keyboard then what i have to do