# Simulate Touch event on EditText to show soft keyboard

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-softkeyboard, android-touch-event

I have a invisible EditText: **ReplyInput** and a button: **ShowReply**.

I want to show the ReplyInput and the soft keyboard after ShowReply is clicked.

Anyone has any idea about that?

Thank for reading :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to open Keyboard on Button click in android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8078004/how-to-open-keyboard-on-button-click-in-android)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like that:

```
InputMethodManager manager = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
manager.showSoftInput(ReplyInput, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
```

Answer (score 0):

One way is to make EditText visible upon clicking on Button and using `InputMethodManager` to bring up soft keyboard ([Here's how to do it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8078341/4260559)), but there's a better way and that is to show EditText and then put focus on it, this way soft-keyboard will be brought up automatically.